# Can I turn down an accepted offer?

Tags: job-acceptance

I have decided to turn down an offer after accepting it.

Actually I just said OK over mail and requested for a hike in salary offered in same mail which was not accepted.

But I have not signed the PDF they sent me.

Can I do this ?

Comment: https://youtu.be/QhjBlPucpd0

Comment: Voting toclose. We don't give legal advice.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it not explicitly asking for legal advice. I think OrbWeaver's answer both deals with the question appropriately and avoids being legal advice. Vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Not being a lawyer I cannot speak to the legal question of whether a contract technically exists or not. However it seems realistically unlikely that a company would sue you for refusing an offer, even if you had notionally accepted it in some way. Taking someone to court costs a lot of money, and the amount of damages they would recover are most likely minimal (or zero) unless the company has already made significant financial commitments on the basis of your acceptance (e.g. by purchasing expensive equipment or something).

The most likely outcome is that the company gets a bit annoyed and probably won't consider you for future positions. But as others have mentioned, this is not a site for legal advice. If you want a definite answer you need to ask a lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not illegal.  Turn it down.

Comment: Depending on your jurisdiction, answering "OK" via mail (or even in verbal discussions) could very well constitute a binding contract, which the OP would renege on. (I don't think any employer would sue someone over it, though.) This is *exactly* why we don't give legal advice here.